# Application Helper Spec, test controller-specific output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, ruby-on-rails-3.1, helper

I'm a little unsure as to how to write a test for a helper method which has output that is based on the given controller and action that are requested.

Given the following helper method in my application helper...

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def body_id
    [ controller.controller_name, controller.action_name ].join("_")
  end
end
```

... how would you write an `application_helper_spec` that tests this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign or mock the controller object. That will give you something to test against. (RSpec includes a very good mocking/stubbing library.)

Comment: I'm kind of an rspec noob, do you mind sharing a link or an example of how to mock/stub this?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Basically, take a look at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec . Since `helper` is available, you could stub `helper.controller` to return an object with a known `controller_name` and `action_name`, then test that you're processing those values as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that got me on track.

Comment: Oh, hey, just noticed something else. The fact that your function is called `body_id` suggests that you're trying to make an `id` attribute for your `<body>` element. Don't ever do that -- since there's only one `<body>` element in any document, it's never appropriate for it to have an `id` element. Instead, modularize your CSS and JS more finely.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser: Would using an ID on the `<body>` tag actually break anything, or is that just purist pedantry?

Comment: It's poor practice. Its sole purpose is to enable the use of big, do-everything CSS and JS files, which in turn take longer to download than they need to (because they're so big), and are more brittle than they should be (because of diminished specificity issues). So it's a symptom of a practice that slows down site responsiveness and makes things more brittle. If it doesn't actually *break* things, it comes damn close. Do it right: use the DOM rather than fighting it.

Answer (score 0):

rspec-rails has some built sugar for testing helpers as @marnen-laibow-koser mentioned. But I sometimes like to write very lightweight tests for my helpers that don't have to load in my whole rails environment. This way the tests can run in less than a second as opposed to the multiple seconds it takes to load the rails environment.

Here is an example:

```
require 'spec_helper_lite'
require_relative '../../app/helpers/application_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do
  let(:helper) do
    class Helper
      include ApplicationHelper
    end
    Helper.new
  end

  it "formats an elapsed time as a number of minutes and seconds" do
    helper.elapsed_as_min_sec(90).should == "1min 30sec"
  end
end
```

And my spec_helper_lite.rb file just looks like this:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/autorun'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.order = "random"
end
```